# Writing a stored procedure to retrieve data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Im trying to write a stored procedure to replace the below query,  the entire query along with the php coding is below

```
$sql = "SELECT name, bachelor FROM boys WHERE id=$ID;";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $connect);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $obj->names = $row['name'];
            $obj->bachelors = $row['bachelor'];
        }

        return $obj;
```

following is the table that I try to retrieve data

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | name      | bachelor |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 | fred      |    1 | 
|  2 | trumen    |    0 | 
|  3 | pat       |    0 | 
|  4 | Mark      |    1 | 
|  5 | Chris     |    1 | 
+----+-----------+-------+
```

currently im retrieving the check box value to determine whether it’s a bachelor or not and the name through the database query. The problem im facing right now is I cannot make the same thing happen through a stored procedure. Therefore will anybody be able to help  me over this????

My failed stored procedure is the following

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllBoys()
    -> BEGIN
    ->      SELECT * FROM boys;
    -> END 
    -> $$
```

Comment: You can change your query in stored procedure. And there is no need to make a procedure for the same while you can done your work efficiently with the query.

Answer (score 0):

Return values of stored procedures aren't result sets.
The maximum you can do in this direction is to use multidimensional arrays as results from your procedure (if you think that is easier to handle).

Answer (score 0):

If your want to check whether the person with input id is a bachelor or not, you have to pass it to stored procedure as an input parameter.
Change SP accordingly.

**Example**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllBoys( IN _id INT )
      SELECT name, bachelor FROM boys WHERE ID = _id;
```

I suggest you go with [*Prepared Statement*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to bind input values with the SQL queries.

**Example**:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( "call GetAllBoys( ? )" );
$stmt->bind_param( "i", $ID );
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: thanks everyone... i got it done.. your answers were very much helpful